# Разделить количество блоков на два

Tags: php, html, css

Ув. Знатоки помогите с решением данной задачи.

В бд есть запись в которой указано количество блоков к примеру 6.
Нужно разделить это число и создать **два** основных div - элемента с разными классами, в которых будет уже по **3** пустых div.

Как такое реализовать? 
Заранее большое спасибо)

Comment: А если в бд будет записано 7? делим на 2 блока и по 3.5 в каждый?

Comment: В бд может быть записано только 6,8,10 и 12.

Comment: Тогда в чем сложность? ваш код может приведете? скажете что у вас не получается?)